# If a cell in column G matches a cell in column J, then make the cell in column G to match the color of the cell in column J

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to do the following. If a cell's value in column G matches a cell's value in column J, then make the cell in column G to match the color of the cell in column J.

I've used the =MATCH() to see in another column if a cell in column G matches a cell in column J, but I really want to copy the cell's color in column J to the cell in column G. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: You can't copy the color of a cell to another with conditional formatting. The format is set within the conditional formatting rule and can't reference a cell.

Comment: As BigBen says it's not possible with default conditional formatting or formulas. It should be possible with VBA or using VBA to create a user defined function (UDF).

Comment: If you can use VBA then this can be easily done: 'Range("G1").Interior.Color = Range("J1").Interior.Color', but you will need the code to look for the cell value in column G then find the cell in column J that has the matching value and run on worksheet_change

Comment: @5202456 Unfortunately, I'm not really a VBA person.